# Identify updated field in update or create django

Tags: python, django

How do I detect which data has been updated and which has been created in a `MyModel.objects.update_or_create()` method?

```
try:
    new_data = MyModel.objects.update_or_create(
        data_1 = active_sheet["{}{}".format("A", row)].value,
        data_2 = active_sheet["{}{}".format("B", row)].value,
    )  
    # default url
    url = reverse('admin:index') + 'some-url/'
    # if some users were only updated, not uploaded
        # pass the updated data to custom template 
        # return the current page with a table of the entries that were not added  
    self.message_user(request, 'Tagged Profile uploaded.')   
    # redirect to selected url
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
except Exception as e:
    messages.warning(request, '%s. If you are seing this, there is an error in your file.' % e)
```

Comment: as I rember new data doesn't have PK before you `save()` it.

Comment: @furas Got it working with an exists(). The function I have now is if model exists, add model to list else create model. I don't know if it's the standard way, but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on documentation [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) returns two values `(object, created)` and if `created` is `True` then it is new object.

The same way works [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with exists().

```
try:
    if MyModel.objects.filter(
        name = active_sheet["{}{}".format("A", row)].value,
    ).exists():
        # add data to list 
    else: 
        # save the new user into the user model
        MyModel.objects.create(
            name = active_sheet["{}{}".format("A", row)].value,
        )
except Exception as e:
    messages.warning(request, '%s. If you are seing this, there is an error in your file.' % e)
```